# Как сделать блоки с картинками и текстом?

Tags: java, android, blocks

Хочу сделать блоки, в которых будет размещена информация, в моем случае картинка с текстом.
Я придумал использовать ЛайнерЛэйауты, но в СкроллВью помещается один ЛайнерЛэйаут, может кто знает другой контейнер?

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
     <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#281e0f46"
        android:padding="13dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">
         <ImageView
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
             android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
             android:src="@drawable/sheya_1"
             android:scaleType="fitStart"
             android:adjustViewBounds="true"
             android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:text="@string/sheya1"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Сдаётся мне, вы изобретаете свой велосипедный и кривоватый `ListView`. Так почему бы не использовать сразу его?

Comment: @falstaf, ТС пока разметку правильную скляпать не может, чего ему там до ListView и его кастомных адаптеров.

Comment: @SuperCreeper, а там разве есть какие-то сложности? В документации `ListView` и всё, что с ним связано, рассмотрены довольно-таки подробно, да ещё и с примерами. Ну и лучше уж сразу приучаться делать правильно, как мне кажется. Даже если это займёт чуть больше времени.

Comment: @falstaf, а если элементы все разные? Например, в одном картинка, в другом текст, а в другом какой-нибудь VideoView? Лично мне кажется, что будет проще сделать через ScrollView.

Comment: > Хочу сделать блоки, в которых будет размещена информация, в моем случае картинка с текстом

Судя по этому, структура блоков будет одинаковой. Да и в случае разных я бы предпочёл использовать `ListView`, учитывая его удобство и плюшки, которые он даёт. И как раз для этого в `BaseAdapter` имеется поддержка различных `view types`: `getViewTypeCount()` и `getItemViewTipe()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В ScrollView вмещается только один прокручиваемый контейнер, в вашем случае LinearLayout. Сделайте вертикальную ориентацию у вашего контейнера и кладите в него другие LinearLayout'ы с нужным содержимым. Вот, такая разметка будет работать:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/myview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <!-- Контейнер -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <!-- Внутри контейнера помещайте любое -->
        <!-- количество нужных элементов -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#281e0f46"
            android:padding="13dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:src="@drawable/sheya_1"
                android:scaleType="fitStart"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:background=" @android:color/holo_blue_light"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:text="@string/sheya1"
                android:layout_gravity="center"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: http://hkar.ru/uJR3, репутация маловато, вот, мне нужны такие блоки, но в скролвью помещается только оид ЛайнерЛэйаут, я хочу найти замену ЛайнерЛэйауту, что бы в нутри скроллвью было много таких "Блоков"

Comment: Спасибо, огроменное!)